# How to wire an HC-SR04 without a breadboard?

Tags: gpio, electronics, wiring

I have a Raspberry Pi and a HC-SR04 integrated circuit for measuring distance. I have found many resources for how to connect the HC-SR04 to the GPIO of the Raspberry Pi, but because the HC-SR04 outputs at 5V, it is necessary to use two resistors to divide the voltage and everything I've found only shows how to connect the HC-SR04 to the RPi via a breadboard.

The schematic is not terribly complicated: 
[image]

I have the necessary resistors and numerous jumper wires, I'm just not sure how to wire it all up without a breadboard. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not really a Pi specific question.

Answer (score 3):

The HC-SR04 is touted as a drop in replacement for the SN-SR04T. While I haven't tested this, I connect the SN-SR04T thusly

- Pin 4 connects directly to the +5V connector
- Pin 6 Connects directly to the GND connector, but is incorporated into the voltage divider for the Echo pin.
- Pin 8 connects to the centre of the voltage divider.
- Pin 10 connects directly to the Trig connector.

[image]

And the power supply connection can be seen a bit better here

[image]

See the book [Raspberry Pi Computing: Ultrasonic Distance Measurement](https://leanpub.com/rpcultra/read) online for some extra details.